# When does a data type means more than its storage space to the compiler?

Tags: c++, c, types, type-conversion

Say I have the following variable declaration:

```
float f = 23.4;
```

Now this means two things (maybe more?):

1. It tells the compiler to allocate 4 bytes of storage in memory.
2. It tells the compiler to treat the bits contained in this 4 bytes storage as a real number.

Now my question is when does `f` gets treated as a real number by the compiler and not just as a storage space of 4 bytes? I can think of the following scenarios:

1. When I assign it a number (e.g. 23.4), the compiler will convert this number to the corresponding bits that represents a real number and place it into `f`.
2. When I assign it an `int` variable, the `int` variable will be converted (casted) to the bits that represents a real number and place into `f` (even if that meant data loss). Or when I try to assign to it a data type that is not allowed (e.g. a `struct`) the compiler will complain.
3. When I use it as an operand in an arithmetic operation, for example `i + f`, the compiler will know that `f` is a `float` and `i` is an `int` and so will not just add the bits contained in `f` and `i` together, but rather it will add what these bits represents.

But when for example I want to output `f` to the console, the compiler has nothing to do with it. So when I use `printf()` it is I who tell `printf()` what does `f` represents (by specifying an `%f` argument). Or when I want to read input from the console, it is also I who tell `scanf()` that I want to convert the received bytes from the user to a real number (by specifying an `%f` argument).

So is there any other scenarios where the compiler is the one responsible for interpreting the content of a variable?

Comment: your line of code defines a double then converts it to float.  suggest: float f = 23.4f;  // notice the trailing 'f' that tells the compiler that it is a float value.

Comment: It would be more appopriate to ask when it *doesn't* mean more than its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ultimately asking how compilers work and how they handle type information and data representation. The answer here is broad and there are multiple approaches:

Some compilers carry out *type erasure*, so that there is no information about what type a particular variable is when it is in memory. How does a compiler know how it should treat the data when you call `printf`? Well, because you told it the type. Compilers that exhibit type erasure make sure that for any variables, all types are known on compile time, thus when translating a higher level program into machine language, and you, say, add two variables together, it knows whether to perform integer addition or floating point addition, because it knows the types of the variables involved. It can also know how it should pass the variable to be printed, etc.

Some interpreters, and managed compilers, on the other hand, do not exhibit *type erasure*. Instead, these compilers encode, as part of the variable itself, a code that represents the type of the variable. This allows the interpreter to check during runtime what the variable is, cast it if necessary, and decide what operations to perform on it.

---

Note that integers and single-precision floating point numbers are represented very differently in memory (though both occupy 4 bytes in most languages and architectures). To know how to display or add something, the compiler needs to know what type it is. The compiler can either emit code that decides that on runtime (some managed programs), or an interpreter can decide to what to do with it on runtime, or the compiler could require to know what every variable is on compile-time, thus eliminating the need to store and specify the type in memory on runtime.

---

In C, `printf` is one of the areas where the language shows that it is not completely type safe (it initially baffled me why anyone would say C isn't type safe when it clearly had types and *seemed* strongly typed).

Notice that in C++, using `std::cout`, you can output an `int`, `double`, `std::string`, etc. without telling the compiler what you are outputting. This is because for `std::cout`, the C++ compiler will figure out the type of the variable on compile-time and call the appropriate `<<` overload, which properly formats the chunk of memory representing the variable, either as an `int`, a `double`, a `std::string`, or whatever it is.

For `printf`, however, the spec of the function was designed to accept a bunch of *"data"* and print that. I'm sure there are interesting and historic reasons why this is the case. The most obvious one is that variable-length arguments cannot be described in multiple types, thus the arguments passed to printf are of some "any" type.. but at that point when compiling the body of the function, the compiler knows that there is a variable number of arguments passed, but does not know the types of each of these.

Had you provided dozens of overloads for `printf`, where every combination and permutation of the different possible types were included, up to some length, then you would have been able to avoid hinting the program what the types are on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is an answer to your question, strictly speaking, but rather it sounds like you're misunderstanding something.

To begin with, there are a couple of errors in your assumptions:

- The declaration of a `float` variable does not tell the compiler to "allocate 4 bytes of storage in memory". It tells the compiler to allocate a `float`, but whether it is allocated in memory, in a register, completely implicitly (with no *real* storage) or, conceivably, in some completely other manner is up to the compiler. For all the C specification cares, the compiler could use your sound card to store the `float` in an audio delay loop between the speakers and microphone.
- The compiler is very much involved even when you pass a `float` to `printf()`. You may have gotten the idea that it simply copies four bytes onto the stack, but that is a mere coincidence of the x86 ABI. Even on AMD64, this is not true, and a `float` argument to a varargs function will be passed in a SSE register (as opposed to `int` arguments which are passed in the integer GPRs, so the compiler very much makes a difference).

It is true, of course, that the compiler does not tell `printf()` to fetch a `float` to print it, but that that responsibility lies with you, but that is not because the compiler "ignores" the contents of your `float` variable, but rather simply because there is no runtime type information passed to functions, and therefore `printf()` needs information on what kind of value to fetch from the call frame. Or, perhaps, in other words, even though the compiler knows about the data type of the value and adjusts the generated code accordingly to match the ABI and everything, it is not obliged to tell `printf()` what it has passed to it, and therefore you need to tell `printf()` about it in its place.

From that perspective, to answer your question, a data type always means more than just its storage size to the compiler, but I feel like the actual question you want to ask is something else.

Answer (score -3):

please check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

it is a bit more then just a 4 bytes of storage.

the whole CPU floating point arithmetic based on the compiler producing correct instruction set and knowing about data type,

of course you can allocate 4 bytes of storage, fake it as real number ( cast ), but that will be just an equivalent of shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: A `float` is not a double-precision number.